# Fullcalendar event date range not past to following month

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Javascript

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        editable: true,
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        nextDayThreshold:'00:00',
                        events: SITEURL + "/leave_calendar",
                        displayEventTime: false,
                        selectable: true,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        eventStartEditable: false,
                        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {  
                           element.find('.fc-title').prepend(event.leave_name)},
```

Event data in JSON
[image]

Result: June Calendar
[image]

Result July Calendar
[image]

Date range not show when switch to following month, for example: apply leave event in 1st of June until 7th of July, the date range doesn't show in July month view.

Any solution given will appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: We need to see the event data as well, in JSON format preferably. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ADyson, i added event data, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: In future please add data in JSON format, as text, as I requested. Pictures of data are much less helpful. Luckily you only have one event here so I can copy it by hand quickly, but that would not be the case for a larger set of data.

Comment: Anyway, if we put this event into the calendar as a static event, we can see that it continues into July as expected - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxgejve?editable=true&editors=001 . So I can only assume there is perhaps an issue with your event feed on the server-side. Remember that every time you move to view a new time period in the calendar, fullCalendar will attempt to download new data for that time period from the server.

Comment: So if you move from June to July, fullCalendar will send another request to `/leave_calendar` and expect new event data back. It will send the current start and end dates of the view to the server, so it can return events which are related to that time period. Is it possible that your server doesn't return the correct data for July? You could monitor your browser's Network tool while you're using the calendar, and check what data is returned for each month.